# Testing HTTPS ignores DHE encryption

Tags: linux, nginx, openssl

I am setting up nginx (v1.16.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1) to use https. I use letsencrypt certificate - SHA-256 with RSA encryption. I use TLSv1.2 I test for ssllabs and observatory. Prescribed encryption next line

`ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;`

I test and get that only ECDHE is detected. I tried various combinations.

[image: ecdhe]

The problem is that I need encryption to work correctly with IE11 in versions of Win 7 and Win 8.1, and when testing I get an error

> "Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure"

If on the same ssllabs I see the supported certificates for IE11 Win7, then the support that I am trying to use is indicated.

> LS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

[image: win7ie11]

If I specify a bunch of extra supported encryption, then everything will be fine, but all other encryption methods are WEAK.

OpenSSL supports this type of cipher

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | grep DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128)    Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Config:

```
server {
listen            443 ssl http2;
server_name       test.ru;

ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;
ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl/privkey.pem;
ssl_ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

location / {
        proxy_pass            http://192.168.1.2;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name test.ru;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
}
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `ssl_dhparam` (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_dhparam) for DHE ciphers to work on nginx.

Quote from the documentation:

> By default no parameters are set, and therefore DHE ciphers will not be used.